# How to formally say "they didn't want to finish their work"

Tags: formality

I'm trying to write an essay about our group, and specifically I want to write that one group of people didn't want to finish their work. What would be the most appropriate way to say this because I don't want it to look like I hate them because of their bad behaviour.

The sentence would be: "As the deadline was approaching, I realized that a group of four people didn't want to finish their assigned work."

Comment: If you do not want to criticize their bad behaviour, just say they didn't finish. Don't assume that they didn't _want_ to finish their work just because they didn't finish it.

Comment: You realized that one group was behind schedule and weren’t likely to finish on time.

Comment: Writing requests are off topic.

Answer (score 0):

> As the deadline was approaching, I realized that a group of four
>   people were **procrastinating**.

[procrastinate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/procrastinate) (intransitive):
to put off intentionally the doing of something that should be done